# Ruby on rails - Order sql results starting with a certain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like create a Ruby on Rails line who have the same comportement of

```
select animal_name 
from animal 
where animal_name like '%cat%' --test if name contains cat
order by
 case when animal_name like 'cat%' then 0 else 1 end, -- order with name starting with cat first
 animal_name -- then by name
```

Like :

```
Animal.order().where("lower(animal_name) like lower(?)", "%cat%");
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something? StackOverflow is not a _write-code-for-me_ resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Animal.select(:animal_name).where("animal_name like lower(?)","%cat%").order("case when lower(animal_name) like lower('cat%') then 0 else 1 end ASC, lower(animal_name) ASC")
```